# Method chaining in python like in java?

Tags: java, python

I vaguely remember from my days of Minecraft modding that in java, you can set multiple class variables in one line, like this:

```
SomeBlock.hardness(0.5).isOpaque(True).blastResistance(2).etc.etc
```

Well I was wondering if there was a way to do something similar in python. I have tried doing the same thing in python, but the second one ends up thinking it is supposed to modify the return of the first one instead of the original class.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean method chaining?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I think thats what it was called now that you mention it.

Comment: Please edit your question if that is the case.

Comment: should I edit it or just delete it, because now that I know what to search for there are duplicate questions on this?

Comment: I think it might be using builder pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, in fact it is done the same way it is done in Java: by returning the `self` reference.

```
class SomeBlock(object):
    def hardness(self, blah):
        self.hardness = blah
        return self
    def isOpaque(self, value):
        self.isOpaque = value
        return self

a = SomeBlock()
a.hardness(0.5).isOpaque(true)
```

Comment: just half of a minute too late... ;)

Comment: It should be noted however that this is somewhat uncommon in Python.  Methods which change state (such as `append` on list objects or `clear` on dicts) usually do not return a value.

Comment: Yes, somehow it seems more pythonic, at least to me, to pass a dict of attribute-name, value pairs to a method named set.  You could could have a signature like set(self, attr, value=None).  If isinstance(attr, dict) call setattr on every key-value pair.  If not, call setattr(self, attr value).  The only drawback is that setattr will create an attribute if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a fluent interface, which is desgined to be like that. It is mostly created by returning the same object:

```
class Test:
  def setX(self, x):
    self.x = x
    return self

  def setY(self, x):
    self.y = y
    return self


 t = Test()
 t.setX(12).setY(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

`the second one ends up thinking it is supposed to modify the return of the first one instead of the original class`.  Yes that is the normal Python syntax.  Returning `self` does not create a special syntax.  It just ensures the returned object is the correct one for chaining.

Your initialization task is more commonly coded as

```
class SomeBlock():
    def __init__(self, hardness=None, opaque=False, blastResistance=None):
        self.hardness = hardness
        self.opaque = opaque
        self.blastResistance = blastResistance

ablock = SomeBlock(hardness=0.5, opaque=True, blastResistance=2)
```

And because `Python` does not require methods for accessing attributes, you can also write

```
ablock = SomeBlock()
ablock.hardness = 0.5
...
```

So if a method does return `self`, it's usually to implement a more complex that setting attributes.

It's more common to have method return a new object of the same class.  This is typical, for example, of many of the `numpy` array methods.  `A.dot(B)` returns new array, the result of taking the dot product of `A` and `B`.  `A.dot(B).dot(C)` may look like chaining, but is just a sequence of actions on successive arrays.